# Sample size reduction in diff-in diff fixed-effects analyses

Tags: fixed-effects-model, poisson-regression

I have a question. For some context, I am using a 2x2 diff-in-diff design where I observe individuals over weeks to see whether an intervention leads to more comment submissions, I am using fixed effects for both time periods and individuals. As outcomes are counts, I use poisson regression.

For simplicity, let's say I observe 1000 individuals over 10 weeks. Yet, only 500 of those have submitted more than 0 ideas during the observation period.

When I used the fixed effects specification, those 500 who do not submit at all are being discarded from the analysis as they hold no information. However, I want to make a statement about  all 1000 individuals, and not only about those 500 individuals who submitted.

- Does the fixed effects allow me to make a statement about all individuals, or only about those who submitted at least once?
- I also tried random-effects poisson and pooled poisson with the same results, pooled poisson with slighly different standard errors.
- Is there anyone or any literature that could help with that?

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Welcome. How is your treatment/intervention allocated to individuals?

Comment: The treatment is an exogenous shock that some individuals but not others experience. It happens at one point in time, not staggered. I use a matching procedure but also an unmatched specification for the diff-din-diff.